# Generic Repository not being resolved using Unity

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using repository pattern my datacontext class is as follows,

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext()
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("Customer");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>().ToTable("Orders");
    }
    public IDbSet<T> DBSet<T>() where T : class
    {
        return this.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

I am using a generic repository as follows,

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
{
    IQueryable<T> FindAll();
    T FindById(int id);
    int Add(T TEntity);
    int Update(T TEntity);
    int Delete(T TEntity);
    int Commit();
}
```

The implementation is,

```
public class SqlRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private DataContext _context;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbSet;
    bool disposing;
    public SqlRepository()
    {
        _context = new DataContext();
        _dbSet = _context.DBSet<T>();
    }
    public IQueryable<T> FindAll()
    {
        return _dbSet;
    }

    public T FindById(int id)
    {
        return _dbSet.Find(id);
    }
```

I am using configuration based container as,

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <assembly name="CustomerManagementAPI.Data"/>
  <namespace name="CustomerManagementAPI.Data"/>
  <container>
    <register type="IRepository" mapTo="SqlRepository">
      <lifetime type="singleton"/>
    </register>
    <register type="ICustomerService" mapTo="CustomerService">
      <lifetime type="singleton"/>
    </register>
  </container>
</unity>
```

while trying to instantiate the controller with parameters I am getting following error
The type name or alias IRepository could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register it as generic:

```
<register type="IRepository[]" mapTo="SqlRepository[]">
  <lifetime type="singleton"/>
</register>
```